# Converting .osm.pbf to .osm

Tags: openstreetmap

I am trying to convert a .osm.pbf file to a .osm file.

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Quick_Install_(Windows)
I followed the instructions here:

- Installed Java Runtime
- Downloaded osmosis and extracted it to a directory
- Created a bat file containing  "C:\Users\paul\Desktop\osmosis\bin\osmosis.bat"

In a dos command prompt when im in the directory of where the batch file I created is located I try:

```
osmosis --read-pbf c:\dir\somefile.osm.pbf --write-xml c:\dir\somefile.osm
```

It just runs really quickly and doesnt convert the file and gives this output:

```
Nov 24, 2021 4:40:20 PM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Osmosis Version 0.48.3
Nov 24, 2021 4:40:22 PM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Preparing pipeline.
Nov 24, 2021 4:40:22 PM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Launching pipeline execution.
Nov 24, 2021 4:40:22 PM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Pipeline executing, waiting for completion.
Nov 24, 2021 4:40:22 PM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Pipeline complete.
Nov 24, 2021 4:40:22 PM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Total execution time: 2297 milliseconds.
```

Comment: I'm not sure what went wrong here. However meanwhile using [osmium-tool](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/) for such tasks is preferred. Unfortunately there is no Windows build available for osmium-tool, but maybe it runs under WSL.

Answer (score 2):

Some sources provide a `.osm.bz2` or `.osm.zip` format which uses standard compression. You can use a program like 7zip to covert those files to a raw `.osm` file. This format is the easiest to convert to a raw `.osm`.

However if you need to convert a binary `.pbf` to a raw `.osm` I would recommend the tool [OSM Convert](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert). Download the large file support version. Unfortunately Osmosis has been unmaintained since September 2018, so try to use newer tools. There is a list of them kept [here on the OpenStreetMap Wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF/Software_Compliance).

With OSM Convert I've used this command with success on Windows 10: `osmconvert us-latest.osm.pbf --out-osm -o=us-latest.osm_01.osm` to convert `us-latest.osm.pbf` to `us-latest.osm_01.osm`